# vscode. Как вызывать таски из других таск?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я сейчас не говорю про dependsOn
Меня интересует вызов последовательных таск. С передачей туда аргументов

```
...
"command": [
     task1 arg1 arg2,
     task1 arg1 arg3
 ]
```

Интересует данный функционал. Пожалуйста, не предлагайте написать скрипт и положить рядом.